# bigquery UDF support

Tags: google-bigquery

I am very new to BigQuery by google

I want to parse time stamp  (`yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mm:ss`) based on the day and the month wish to bucket days into weeks.
I didn't find any BigQuery function which does this.

Hence, I was wondering if there was a way in which I can write a `UDF` and then access it in a BigQuery query

Comment: UDFs available now: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions here, so two answers:

- BigQuery **does** support UDFs: [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions). (It didn't when I first answered this.)
- Even without UDFs, the date bucketing is still doable. BigQuery has one time parsing function, `PARSE_UTC_USEC`, which is expecting input in the form `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. You'll need to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to get your date into the right format. Once you've done that, `UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK` will block things into weeks, and you can group by that. So tying all that together, if your table has a column called `timestamp`,  you could get counts by week via something like

  ```
  SELECT week, COUNT(week)
  FROM (SELECT UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK(
                 PARSE_UTC_USEC(
                   REGEXP_REPLACE(
                     timestamp, 
                     r"(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})", 
                     r"\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6")), 0) AS week
        FROM mytable) 
  GROUP BY week;
  ```

  Note that the `0` here is the argument for which day of the week to use as the "beginning"; I've used Sunday, but for "business"-y things using `1` (i.e. Monday) would likely make more sense.

Just in case you need it, the [section on timestamp functions](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#timestampfunctions) in the docs is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Craig, Just finished my first analysis of Bigquery and man querying it is fast Really FAST.
Just few concerns about 

a) Lack of UDF support

b) Limitation on Joins

c) Load time issues

Comment: BigQuery has UDF support now: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions

Answer (score 1):

UDF support in BigQuery is now here!  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions

Here is some code that will convert a string time specifier into a JavaScript Date object, and extract some properties from it; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for information on properties available for JS dates.

QUERY (replace the nested select with your table):

```
SELECT day_of_week, month_date
FROM parseDate(select '2015/08/01 12:00:00' as date_string);
```

CODE:

```
function parsedate(row, emit) {
  var d = new Date(row.date_string);
  emit({day_of_week: d.getDay(),
        month_date: d.getDate()});
}

bigquery.defineFunction(
  'parseDate',                           // Name of the function exported to SQL
  ['date_string'],                    // Names of input columns
  [{'name': 'day_of_week', 'type': 'integer'},
   {'name': 'month_date', 'type': 'integer'}],
  parsedate
);
```

Comment: While this link may be helpful, can you add some relevant information in the question so if the link ever dies the information remains?

Comment: Thanks, updated comment with query and code examples.